# TF Lite Retraining on Mobile

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Let's assume I made an app that has machine learning in it using a tflite file.

Is it possible that I could retrain this model right inside the app?

I have tried to use the [Model Maker](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification) which is provided by TensorFlow, but, without this, i don't think there's any other way to retrain your model with just the app i made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean training on the device when the app is deployed? If yes, TFLite currently doesn't support training in general. But there's some experimental work in this direction with limited support as shown by https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/model_personalization.

Currently, the retraining of a TFLite model, as you found out w/ Model Maker, has to happen offline w/ TF before the app is deployed.